# Finding specific letter in string - Not working (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have been trying to find a specific letter from a string, but am having errors. I have an array with about 1000 strings stored, and for each, I want to find the first integer, second integer, specific letter, and an actual word. FOr example, one stored string could be: "1-36 g: guacamole", in which I would want to return the values 1, 36, the letter g, and the word guacamole. So far, I have found ways to get the first two numbers, but not the strings. Is there any way to look for them from their index, or their relative position to the delimiters? Here is my code currently:

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) { // For each stored string, check...
                    
    current = list[x]; // First, set current variable to current word from array
                    
    Matcher first = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(current);
    first.find();
    min = Integer.valueOf(first.group()); // Get minimum value (from example, 1)

    first.find();
    max = Integer.valueOf(first.group()); // Get maximum value (from example, 36)
                    
    first.find();
    letter = String.valueOf(first.group()); // What I am trying to do to get first letter (from example, g)
                    
    System.out.println("Minimum value: " + min + " | Maximum value: " + max + " | Letter: " + letter);
                    
}
```

All that appears in the console is the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

I haven't gotten any code yet to find the word, which I will attempt next. If anyone could help me with that as well, that would be great!

Alternatively, if you could recommend another way to look for these values from each string, that would also be much appreciated. If I should provide any other code, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you capture all at once? Say, with `"(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\s*(\\p{Alpha}+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)"`? See https://ideone.com/JSUrUZ

Answer (score 1):

I just run this on regex101, tried to match from 1-36 g: guacamole
this works for me

```
(\d).(\d+).(.*)\s(\w+)
```

source: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern recordPattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d+).*(\\d+) (.)\\: (.*)$").matcher(current);
for (String record : list) { // For each stored string, check...
    Matcher m = recordPattern.matcher(current);
    if (m.matches()) {
        int min = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int max = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)); 
        String letter = m.group(2);
        String name = m.group(3);
                    
        System.out.printf("Minimum: %d | Maximum: %d | Letter: %s | Name: %s.%n",
              min, max, letter, name);
    }               
}
```

Instead of find one can match the entire line. Alway check the results of `find` resp. `match` as otherwise the matcher's groups are invalid.

To keep the code more readable declare variable just before the usage. There is no penalty in loops (just one variable slot on the call stack). *(I know in early CS it was thought good style to declare all variable at the top.)*

The error was the regex `"\\d+"` which stands for 1 or more **d**igits. The javadoc of the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class